# Django filter date > datetime.now

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a view that displays a list sorted by date. I would like to make a filter to display values ​​where the date is greater than the current date. How to do it correctly?

```
class UpcomingEvents(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset = Event.objects.all().order_by('start_date')
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
```

Comment: Before posting it on Stackoverflow try to give it a try yourself. It would be nice if you could add whatever you tried so far in the question.

Comment: This might be helpful https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the model to reference, the only value we have to work with in your example is **start_date**

You are looking for **filter(xxx__gt)** - official docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/)

Working with what you've given us, it'd be something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
queryset = Event.objects.filter(start_date__gt=datetime.now()).order_by('start_date')
```